# not in feature in sql, confused by manager and employee

Tags: sql, database, select, where-clause, notin

- `EMPLOYEE` (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno); KEY: ssn
- `DEPARTMENT` (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate); KEY: dnumber.
- `PROJECT` (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum); KEY: pnumber.
- `WORKS_ON` (essn, pno, hours); KEY: (essn, pno)
- `DEPENDENT` (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship); KEY: (essn, dependent-name)

Let's say I want to get the last name and SSN of those managers who DO NOT work on any one of the projects located in Cleveland.

The right answer is:

```
  select 
      Lname
  from
      Employee e, Department d
  where  
      (e.ssn = d.mgrssn) 
      and ssn NOT in (select w.essn
                      from works_on w, Project p
                      where w.pno = p.pnumber
                        and p.plocation = 'Cleveland')
```

1. So what are the meaning of `(e.ssn = d.mgrssn)`? is mrgrssn manager's ssn? if so why not just select it, but instead use e.ssn = mgrssn?
2. I know ESS not means, but why not use mgrssn not in? since we are looking for managers, not employee
3. Finally why is `where w.pno = p.pnumber` added, the question did not specifically ask for pnunmber, just location

Comment: will you continue be asking for your homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703580/midterm-solution-around-query-in-sql

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: also can I ask inside the loop, what is select w.essn used for? why are we selecting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to understand a complex query is from the inside out. So:

3) We select all the projects whose location is 'Cleveland', joined to the list of employees who work on each of those projects, to get the list of SSNs of employees working in Cleveland.

1) We join department managers' SSNs to the employee SSNs to get the last names of all department managers.

2) We then select those employees (all of whom are managers, from step 1) whose SSNs are **NOT IN** the list of employees who work in Cleveland (from step 3, which we looked at first.)

In step 2, we want the last names of the managers. Manager SSNs are in `department`, but names aren't, so we need to join to `employee` to get those names.

In step 3 we join on project number because that's how the employees are identified in `works_on`.

Comment: thank you but i thought ess is already e.ssn? not mgrssn

Comment: I assume you mean `essn`. It's a column in `works_on` which **corresponds to, but is not the same column as** the `ssn` column in `employee`. That **correspondence** is how we establish relationships between tables in SQL. `mgrssn` is a column in `department` which has the same correspondence to `employee.ssn`.

Comment: oh I see now. so whenever they are asking for things not in the same column, you have to do a join like "=". because sometimes whenever they are asking for employee there is no essn = mgrssn part

Comment: It's more asking for things that are related but not in the same *table.*

Comment: oh thanks also the solution uses and  ssn NOT in, or sometimes ssn in for other questions. why is that? if we are finding manager, shouldn't mgrssn be used? or are there many ways of doing this solution?

Answer (score 1):

We are equating ssn of manager in two different tables. So that relevent data can be retreived and same happens with pno. That is, to find the result of the required query, we need to find some relation among them. That is what happening in this case.

Comment: also can I ask inside the loop, what is select w.essn used for? why are we selecting that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Manager's ssn is in the department table. You will have to join it to employee to get LName.
2. You can use mgrssn NOT IN instead of ssn NOT IN becasue you are taking records where e.ssn = d.mgrssn. Both values will always be same
3. Location is part of Project table, not works_on. But you need the works_on to relate a project to an employee. Therefore both tables have to be joined.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about d.mgrssn vs mgrssn. There's only one such column so either is ok.

Comment: thank you but i thought ess is already e.ssn? not mgrssn

Comment: also can I ask inside the loop, what is select w.essn used for? why are we selecting that?

Comment: First, there is no loop. Second, it is pretty obvious that the "and ssn NOT IN" would be compared to a list of ssn.